# Javascript - Looping a nested Loop

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, nested-loops

The first loop I tried is in /* */ part of the code. The second code was the do while loop. In both situations the loop just continues and does not reiterate the nested loop. I am not quite sure what i am doing wrong. The while condition might not be right, but my concern is the non resetting of the inner loop. Index does not seem to be reseting to 0.

I am using Google Apps Script

```
function getWorkingSessions() {
  var api_token = "************************";
  var range_start = "2019-09-01";
  var range_end = "2019-09-02";
  var company = "*****";
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Daten Papershift")
  var row = range.getLastRow()+1;
  var pageget = 1

  var options = {
    'method' : 'get',
    'contentType': 'application/json',
  };

  /* var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://app.papershift.com/public_api/v1/working_sessions?api_token=" + api_token + "&range_start=" + range_start + "&range_end=" + range_end + "&page=" + pageget + "&company_id=" + company);
  if (result.getResponseCode() == 200) {
    var session = JSON.parse(result.getContentText());
    var params = session.working_sessions;

   /* for (; page < 3; page++) {
      var resultb = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://app.papershift.com/public_api/v1/working_sessions?api_token=" + api_token + "&range_start=" + range_start + "&range_end=" + range_end + "&page=" + page + "&company_id=" + company);
      var sessions = JSON.parse(resultb.getContentText());
      var workingsessions = sessions.working_sessions;
      var index = 0;

      for (; index < workingsessions.length -1; index++ , row++) {
        range.getRange(row, 1, 1, 1).setValue(workingsessions[index].id);
        var datum = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(workingsessions[index].starts_at), "GMT", "dd.MM.yyyy");
        range.getRange(row, 2, 1, 1).setValue(datum)
        var start = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(workingsessions[index].starts_at), "GMT", "HH:mm");
        range.getRange(row, 3, 1, 1).setValue(start);
        var end = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(workingsessions[index].ends_at), "GMT", "HH:mm");
        range.getRange(row, 4, 1, 1).setValue(end);
        range.getRange(row, 5, 1, 1).setValue(workingsessions[index].location_id);
        range.getRange(row, 6, 1, 1).setValue(workingsessions[index].employee_id);
      };
    }; */
    var page = 1;

    do {
      var resultb = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://app.papershift.com/public_api/v1/working_sessions?api_token=" + api_token + "&range_start=" + range_start + "&range_end=" + range_end + "&page=" + page + "&company_id=" + company);
      var sessions = JSON.parse(resultb.getContentText());
      var workingsessions = sessions.working_sessions;
      var index = 0;
      for (; index < workingsessions.length-1; index++, row++) {
        range.getRange(row, 1, 1, 1).setValue(workingsessions[index].id);
        var datum = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(workingsessions[index].starts_at), "GMT+2", "dd.MM.yyyy");
        range.getRange(row, 2, 1, 1).setValue(datum)
        var start = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(workingsessions[index].starts_at), "GMT+2", "HH:mm");
        range.getRange(row, 3, 1, 1).setValue(start);
        var end = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(workingsessions[index].ends_at), "GMT+2", "HH:mm");
        range.getRange(row, 4, 1, 1).setValue(end);
        range.getRange(row, 5, 1, 1).setValue(workingsessions[index].location_id);
        range.getRange(row, 6, 1, 1).setValue(workingsessions[index].employee_id);
      };
      page++;
    } while ( sessions.next_page != "null" );

 /* } else {}; */
};
```

Comment: " Index does not seem to be reseting to 0", how do you know? According code it does.

Comment: Just a small detail but I noticed that you have an extra comma here `'contentType': 'application/json',};`

Comment: Looks like the only way is that  `sessions.next_page` never get's set to null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Index does go to 0, although I understand your doubts because it's not nice to initialize the conditional variable (index) outside of the for brackets, and it is not nice either to operate other variables than the conditional ones inside the for, you can do it, it works on javascript, but it's not nice.

This works as intended, so your index is certainly going to 0.

```
function getWorkingSessions() {

  var row = 1;

    do {
      var index = 0;
      for (; index < 6; index++, row++) {
        Logger.log(row);
        Logger.log(index);        

      };
    } while ( row<5 );

 /* } else {}; */
};
```

The problem is on the while condition:

```
sessions.next_page != "null"
```

will be always true, cause the API never returns a null string, so called "null"

```
sessions.next_page != null
```

eventually the API returns a null, when there are no more pages, so this expresion will NOT be always true. null is the absence of any object value, "null" is a string that holds the word null.

So, the problem is that the apps script environment is entering in a never ending loop, and thus, it looks like it's not entering on your nested for, but this is because your code is falling into a never ending loop and crashes the environment.

Just do:

```
    } while ( sessions.next_page != null );
```

and you should return to a finite recursive world, not as this infinite capital expansion, so called capitalism, that we live on, that is crashing our environment.

Comment: hey @yuri thanks for the input. sadly it does not solve my problem. Right now I know there are more than 1 page in my call, but the loop stops after the first page.

Comment: Hi Michel, try to summarize the problem, clean the code and open a new question with the new problems that may had arise. 
I believe the original question about not entering on the loop has been solved although your code is still not doing what you intended, and please, if this is the case, upvote the answer ;)